# always open destop version of the website in my app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

iam creating an ios application for a website.i have done everything that i want the only thing missing is the desktop version of the website.its opening the mobile version  instead of desktop version.
can any one help me though the code snippets of how to open the desktop version of the website all the time.Im creating the application for ipad.

Comment: It depends on how your site is working with small screens. If it has responsive design then you have to remove this feature from your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is using a responsive design then there is no way you can do that. On the flip side if you have separate versions for mobile and and desktop then you can modify user agent string to open desktop version of the website, use the below before making web requests within your app

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent": @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"}];
```

you can replace user agent string with what ever user agent you want